# Photoshop simulating printer (lack of white ink) on colored paper

Tags: printer, adobe-photoshop, colors

I want to print something on colored paper. Is it possible to simulate lack of white ink in printer in Photoshop?

I am worried that some colors may be to bright to be actually visible on colored paper or they will be much darker than i expect.

Comment: Make the image transparent and layer on top of another image the same colour as the paper?

Comment: Inks in printers work in the way, that adding more ink can only make the paper darker (additive model). I.e. you can not print white color on non-white paper (or get any color, that is lighter than the paper).